# FAA's suggestion to avoid using "pursuant to", "per", and "in accordance with"

Tags: word-choice

I found an article by FAA advising against the use of "pursuant to", "per", and "in accordance with":

https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/plain_language/articles/differences/

To what extent are those points supported really? In my everyday reading, I found these phrases used pretty frequently in news articles etc. and just don't feel they are that bad.

Comment: Presumably the FAA is urging its own emplyees, when writing FAA information for the public, to use "plain language" rather than jargon like "pursuant to".  Of course it has no effect on what  others (like news writers) do.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a very early "lousy" steers me towards a pet peeve sounding rant..not anything truly grounded. It's more of a generalization that the tired and played, uppity legal slang indicates laziness and/or use of "vintage" terms and phrases designed to improve writer's stature in readers' eyes.

I don't see anything wrong with using them..especially to heavily document.

°Per the Human Resources Hiring Procedures book, scan all resumes before applications.

°Pursuant to Michigan Department of Education's COVID-19 Taskforce guidance dated July 17, 2020, all students in grades K-12 will be required to wear a mask or cloth face covering while on campus, except while eating or drinking, resuming mask usage immediately after.

°In accordance with the US Constitution, state legislatures can certify and confirm a different candidate than seated presidential electors would have.